# AI Doc Writer For Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a plugin in Android studio for Writing comments in a faster way, The Tabnine code completion Plugin is great for Wirting code , but java doc or Other such commenting features are missing, VS code has the Plugin called AI Doc Writer, Is there any thing similar for android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offical AI Doc Writer For Android Studio is available now

[here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18606-ai-doc-writer)

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to do it manually. I also created a request to jetbrains (who developed android studio) for that plugin.

UPDATE: There is one plugin available in jetbrains store. [Mintlify Doc Writer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/organizations/mintlify).

Comment: I came across this while searching for it https://github.com/mintlify/vscode-docs/issues/27#issuecomment-1035952019 , it will be available soon

Comment: Mintlify Doc Writer is an excelent plugin but it does not work with the latest Android Studio: Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1.